# how can we concatnate input field value (in array) with other input field for from submission

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs, forms

I'm editing form's input field data and i know what m going to ask,is not the way to do submission of form data but i was totally stuck to get the value datetimepicker in ng-model(actually i need to say that i got the value in ng-model but not in array as i got the value of another one in array which is named as editAdsData).so i want to submit some input field s value individually.i know most of the ppl will be confused what i want to ask. let's take look of my code everything would be clear.

In view:

//create a form

```
 <form ng-submit="edit_jobs('<?php echo $employer_jobs->id; ?>','<?php echo $employer_jobs->employer_id; ?>')" class="form-preview-display" method="post"  name="submitAdsForm">
    <input type = "hidden" ng-init="editAdsData.comp_name = '<?php echo $employer_jobs->comp_name;?>'">
    <input placeholder="Company Name" id="company_name" value="" name="company_name" ng-model="editAdsData.comp_name" ng-pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" minlength="2" maxlength="150" required form-field="submitAdsForm" type="text" class="form-control">
    <input type = "hidden" ng-init="start_date = '<?php echo $employer_jobs->start_date;?>'">
    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="start_date" name="start_date" ng-model="start_date" datetime-picker date-only />
</form>
```

so editAdsData is an array, where i want to store all input fields value.but i 'm still confused why i'm getting the value of start_date in editAdsData.
That's why i'm trying to post it individually.

So in Controller:

```
  $scope.edit_jobs = function($id,$emp_id){
           Data.editJobs($.param($scope.editAdsData),$.param($scope.start_date),$.param($scope.end_date),$id,$emp_id).success(function (data) {
            if (data.status == 0) {
                // location.reload();
            }else{
                // location.reload();
            }   
        });
    };
```

In services:

```
 this.editJobs = function ($data1,$data2,$data3,$id,$emp_id) {
    return $http.post(site_url + "User/User/editJobsData/" + $id + "/" + $emp_id , $data1 + "<br>" + "[start_date]=>" + $data2 + "<br>" + "[end_date]=>" + $data3);
};
```

and now i want the value of data1,data2 and data3 should be concatnate as we get the value of a single array like:

```
(
[comp_name] => abc
[min_salary] => 123
[max_salary] => 12345
)
```

So, can anyone help me to get this.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you put all your input fields inside of the same object as showing in the following link of the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms. So all ng-models would be object.property.

```
<input placeholder="Company Name" id="company_name" value="" name="company_name" ng-model="user.comp_name" class="form-control">
<input type='text' class="form-control" id="start_date" name="start_date" ng-model="user.start_date" datetime-picker date-only />
<input type="submit" ng-click="save(user)" value="Save" />
```

In your controller just paste the save function:

```
$scope.save= function(user) {
  $scope.user = angular.copy(user);
};
```

Try it like this. You don´t need the $id and $emp_id in the function, because you are passing those values on it. Change start_date and end_date with editAdsData.start_date and declare your editAdsData variable as an object.

```
<form ng-submit="edit_jobs('<?php echo $employer_jobs->id; ?>','<?php echo $employer_jobs->employer_id; ?>')" class="form-preview-display" method="post"  name="submitAdsForm">
    <input type = "hidden" ng-init="editAdsData.comp_name = '<?php echo $employer_jobs->comp_name;?>'">
    <input placeholder="Company Name" id="company_name" value="" name="company_name" ng-model="editAdsData.comp_name" ng-pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" minlength="2" maxlength="150" required form-field="submitAdsForm" type="text" class="form-control">
    <input type = "hidden" ng-init="start_date = '<?php echo $employer_jobs->start_date;?>'">
    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="start_date" name="start_date" ng-model="editAdsData.start_date" datetime-picker date-only />
    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="end_date" name="end_date" ng-model="editAdsData.end_date" datetime-picker date-only />
</form>

var editAdsData = {};
$scope.edit_jobs = function(id, emp_id, editAdsData){
           editAdsData = angular.copy(editAdsData);
           Data.editJobs(editAdsData, editAdsData.start_date, editAdsData.end_date, id, emp_id).success(function (data) {
            if (data.status == 0) {
                // location.reload();
            }else{
                // location.reload();
            }   
        });
};
```

Comment: coz i'm not getting the value of datepicker in object user but if i individually print the {{user.start_date}},it have the value but in object user it's not getting.